# How can I discover existing web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, service-discovery

I'm sure I sound like a total noob with this question, and I've looked at a couple posts that are basically asking the same question in the title, but the body didn't give anything helpful to my skill or knowledge level.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789856/how-do-i-discover-restful-web-services?answertab=active#tab-top) the OP mentioned that they did some "digging and drilling" to find out that there was a web service in REST format. In [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215876/is-there-a-way-to-discover-web-services-on-a-site) I found that the OP was using "web console" to look at the activity of a website they were visiting.

I would really like to have more knowledge and methods for finding web services that I can reference and use is some of my new or updated applications, whether RESTful or not. In summary, how do I "dig and drill" to find that a site has a web service I can use programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sensible way to find web services that you can use is to ask.

- If the service is intended for your use, then you will be told that.
- If the service is not intended for your use, then you will be told *that*.
- If you use a service that is not intended for your use, then that will generally be a bad thing.

Comment: to whom would I target my asking? How would I know to ask if a service is intended for my use if I don't know there is one?

Comment: If you don't know to ask, then you don't need the service. Why do you imagine there are services for you to call, and nobody has told you about them?