# Is there any repository like UDDI for publishing and discovering RESTful web service?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, uddi, juddi

I am a novice to web service repository and i want to discover REST based service matching a keyword phrase or some parameters. Is there any repository available like UDDI for SOAP services?

Here are the links where related topics have been discussed

1 [How do I discover RESTful Web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789856/how-do-i-discover-restful-web-services)

2  [publishing and discovering REST web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976159/publishing-and-discovering-rest-web-services)

but no where it has been explicitly described how to pursue this task(like a complete tutorial link where RESTFUL web service has been published and retrieved )

Hope to get a well explained answer

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend on what product are you using for discovery.

MDNS, try using [JNDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) for Java. The method you want is probe and you'll have to listen for responses to the query for some predefined String that represents your endpoint. Sometimes people us DNS TXT records or SRV locators for the URL. [Here's a good example](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/jmdns/code/tags/jmdns-3.4.1/src/sample/java/samples/ListServices.java)

UDDI, specifically jUDDI (and 1 or two others) has a REST API that you can invoke. It works well if you know the 'key', or a unique identifier of the service. Since UDDI's data is complex, jUDDI has a FindEndpoints method which can return JSON or XML structures. HTTP GET to http://localhost:8080/juddiv3/services/inquiryRest/{XML,JSON}/endpointsByService/{id}
The response is of type [UriContainer](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/uddi-ws/src/main/java/org/apache/juddi/api_v3/rest/UriContainer.java), which is just a list of Strings, each representing a valid URL that you should be able to do something with. There's a few more examples in the TCK Tests for juddi [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/juddi/trunk/uddi-tck/src/test/java/org/apache/juddi/v3/tck/UDDI_160_RESTIntergrationTest.java)

Comment: Actaully , I am working on a college project where i have used three restful web services and for that i had made MYSQL as my web service repository(so i had added web service description in MYSQL) but my teacher yesterday said that we need Repository(something like you have mentioned in your comment),if web service repository just returns a URL for the requested kind of web service then why can't i use MYSQL as it solves the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

repository solution can provide some facilities such as service discovery, event notification that a normal DBMS cannot.

Comment: This is not an answer you should have given it in a comment section